# Using an image to submit a search form

Tags: html, search, forms

I have done this a lot of times but I have a problem, I'm trying to do it with the google form, the google name have slashes so is not working on all browsers, is there a different way to do this?

Any clue is good :D

code:

```
        <form action="http://www.webpage.com/search.php" id="cse-search-box" name="cse-search-box">
          <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="partner-pub-number" />
            <input type="hidden" name="cof" value="FORID:number" />
            <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="ISO-8859-1" />
            <input type="text" name="q" size="31" class="form-search" />
        <a name="sa" id="sa" href="javascript:document.cse-search-box.submit();"><img src="images/arrow.jpg" class="img-search"/></a>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Those are called hyphens, not slashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<input type="image" src="path/image.png" />
```

Comment: sorry for the dumb question :D but I was blocked and forgot that I can do that :D

Answer (score 3):

`<input type="image" ...>` is what is used for images acting as submit buttons.

Answer (score 2):

`-` is the minus operator, so `document.cse-search-box` doesn't mean what you think it does -- further, this way of accessing elements is obsolete. Use [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.getElementById) instead:

```
document.getElementById('cse-search-box').submit();
```

Actually, you don't even need JavaScript to do this. There are at least 2 ways to do it using HTML alone:

```
<input type="image" src="images/arrow.jpg" />
```

or:

```
<button type="submit"><img src="images/arrow.jpg" /></button>
```